# JList - selecting option

Tags: java, jlist

how do i go do this, based on input in textfield, you get some results inside jlist, after you select option in jlist you then get an action, code examples would be appreciated... this is what i got so far:

```
final DefaultListModel<String> locations = new DefaultListModel<String>();

    getTextFieldSearch().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
                locations.add(i, "blah");
            }
        }
    });


    JList<String> list_racentRaces = new JList<String>(locations);
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), which has lots of awesome code examples.

The basic idea would be to...

When your `actionPerformed` method is triggered, create a new `DefaultListModel`, assuming you don't have your own implementation, fill it with all the new items you need and apply it to the instance of `list_racentRaces`

If you want to maintain what was previously in the list, you should consider starting with a `DefaultListModel` and simply add the new items to it as you need to...

Then, attach a `ListSelectionListener` to `list_racentRaces` and when the `valueChanged` event is triggered, find the selected item(s) and do what ever you need to based on these result(s)

You can find more details and examples through [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)